# Що таке "верше" у пісні "Ой, верше мій верше"?

Tags: значення-слів, лемківський-діалект

Мабуть багато знають народну лемківську пісню "[Ой, верше мій верше](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/322626.html)":

> Ой верше мій, верше,
>   Мій зелений верше,
>   Юж мі так не буде,
>   Як мі било перше.

Невідоме мені слово *верше*. Інформації щодо нього в словниках не знайшла, на цьому [сайті](https://m.facebook.com/chystamova/posts/534648340024614) є обговорення в якому висловлюють думки що це може бути *дуб, жито, гора, пристосування для ловлі риби*. Найбільш правильним, на мою думку, є припущення що це гора. Та підтвердження цьому не знайшла.
То ж що таке *верше*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Схоже що "верх" значить "гора". [Стаття про лемків](http://spadok.org.ua/lemkivshchyna/lemky-istorychna-dolya-pokhodzhennya) так описує гори, які входять до території Лемківщини:

> Лемківські гори займають при кордонному краї Карпат від сходу Кізляту Гору з Вяселем, **Загірянські верхи**, Тирявські, Вільховецькі, Білогорські, Лішнянські узгіря, що разом зі Сторожівськими горбовинами вінком окружують Сяніцькі Землі. Дальше розтаборились Команчансько-Лупківські високорівні, **Вислочансько-Мощанецькі верхи**, Дуклянські гори, Діли, Губині, Явірники, Габурі, Кичери, (Кучери), Мережки. Від заходу сторчить **Студений Верх**, Явориста гора, **верх Тисове**, Бліхнарська Висока, **Гострий верх**, Високі гори з Берестям, дальше Зимний Шпиль, Вапенні гори та Скальські узгіря над річкою Скалкою.

Тобто "верше, мій верше" - це кличний відмінок від слова "верх".